# How to record sound by using inbuilt microphone in android

Tags: android, microphone

I need to record sound by using mobile's own microphone... How to do it?

Comment: You should use Google and the the search function here on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture)

> Audio capture from the device is a bit
>   more complicated than audio/video
>   playback, but still fairly simple:
>
> 1. Create a new instance of android.media.MediaRecorder using new
> 2. Set the audio source using MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(). You
>      will probably want to use
>      MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
> 3. Set output file format using MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat()
> 4. Set output file name using MediaRecorder.setOutputFile()
> 5. Set the audio encoder using MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder()
> 6. Call MediaRecorder.prepare() on the MediaRecorder instance.
> 7. To start audio capture, call MediaRecorder.start().
> 8. To stop audio capture, call MediaRecorder.stop().
> 9. When you are done with the MediaRecorder instance, call
>      MediaRecorder.release() on it. Calling
>      MediaRecorder.release() is always
>      recommended to free the resource
>      immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Example:

To start recording:

```
        MediaRecorder audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(AUDIO_FILE_PATH);

        try {
            audioRecorder.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        audioRecorder.start();
```

To stop recording:

```
        audioRecorder.stop();
        audioRecorder.release();
```