# How to record the app's sounds via phone

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I do have an app, which makes some sounds. Lets to say similar to soundboard. So, I want to record the output of my app, and then play it back. I looked over `MediaRecorder` but I have to show a `source` and it can be only a `MIC`. After Googling and stackOverflowing, I did not find what I was looking for.

I would like to have from you some suggestions on this, as I dont know how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261241/how-to-record-sound-by-using-inbuilt-microphone-in-android

Comment: @Barney, as I mentioned `MediaRecorder` asks for source which can be a `MIC`. I dont want to record from `MIC`, I want to record the output of application itself. and it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

mediaRecord  or AudioRecord AFAIK only record from a device. rather than piping audio like a mixer, just pipe the raw data. Use a RandomAccessFile in a service or something like that. think like a computer, not a tape recorder.

Comment: didnt get you. Any articles, any link, any examples? so i can refer to